# Where are Postgresql 9.1 logs? (not starting on FreeBSD 10)

Tags: postgresql, logging, freebsd

I tried finding solutions, but nothing helps.

I need to do a backup of my pgsql data from the app, I haven't used for months now. I have discovered, that the postgresql server is not running. But cannot start it.

I run `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data -l logging.log -w -s start` as `pgsql` user (su pgsql). Output says that it couldn't start a server and tells me to check logs. But logging.log is an empty file. Any default logging file I have found on the web about is modified months ago or empty or even doesn't exist.

I have no idea how to find the error, since logs are empty or I just don't know where to look for them.

Important note: it was working few months ago, but there were almost no changes in that time (possible hostname change).

- Postgres is v9.1
- System: FreeBSD 10.0-RC4

Comment: Did you check `/usr/local/pgsql/data/pg_log` for logfiles?

Comment: Is there a -verbose command when starting this? It may provide more information..

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I don't have this dir/file at all :/ There are pg_xlog and pg_clog, but old and have nothing interesting too

Comment: @ryekayo - I can do `sh -x /usr/local/etc/rc.d/postgresql start` and then I get lots of data, but ends with `+ su -l pgsql -c 'exec /usr/local/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data -w -s -m fast start'` which is quite same as I have written above. And ends with `pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
+ _return=1
+ [ 1 -ne 0 ]
+ [ -z '' ]
+ return 1
+ return 1
`. But... there's no log :/

Comment: Check `/usr/local/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf` file and see if (1) `logging_collector` is on and (2) what is the value of `log_directory`. If `logging_collector` is enabled, then the logs are saved in `log_directory` path.

Comment: Well, it was off, so I turned it on, and set dir to pg_log (it is default too). Tried, but got inside only empty `postgresql-2014-12-09_212815.log` file.

Answer (score 6):

Some versions of FreeBSD ports installed PostgreSQL with syslog logging enabled. You can confirm this by looking at `/usr/local/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf` for `log_destination = 'syslog'`

If that is the case, the logging output should be visible in `/var/log/messages`

Answer (score 0):

Default syslog logging enabled (log_destination = 'syslog') and  logging output should be visible in /var/log/messages.

If you want to make a log in a separate file:

1) Create log file:

```
touch /var/log/postgresql/postgresql.log
```

2) Edit /etc/syslog.conf, append lines

```
!postgres
*.*                                             /var/log/postgresql/postgresql.log
!*
```

After editing, you need to restart the service

```
service syslogd restart
```

4) do not forget to rotate postgresql.log (edit /etc/newsyslog.conf)

5) Perhaps in order to see something you will need to set the logging level. As an example, add to your postgresql.conf

```
client_min_messages = log
log_min_messages = info

log_checkpoints = on
log_connections = on
log_disconnections = on
```